# Delphi Tidtcpserver with a peek from the buffer

Tags: delphi, indy

How can I read a message from a tidtcpserver context without removing it from the read buffer?  I want to preview the message and leave it where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Indy is not really designed for *peeking* data, it would rather that you *read* whole data, letting it block until the requested data has arrived in full.

That being said, `TIdBuffer` does have a `PeekByte()` method:

```pascal
function PeekByte(AIndex: Integer): Byte;
```

```pascal
var
  B: Byte;

if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size > 0 then
begin
  B := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.PeekByte(0);
  ...
end;
```

Or, if you are looking for something in particular in the buffer (ie, a message delimiter, etc), `TIdBuffer` has several overloaded `IndexOf()` methods:

```pascal
function IndexOf(const AByte: Byte; AStartPos: Integer = 0): Integer; overload;
function IndexOf(const ABytes: TIdBytes; AStartPos: Integer = 0): Integer; overload;
function IndexOf(const AString: string; AStartPos: Integer = 0;
  AByteEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ASrcEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}
): Integer; overload;
```

```pascal
var
  Index: Integer;

Index := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.IndexOf(SingleByte);
Index := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.IndexOf(ArrayOfBytes);
Index := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.IndexOf('string');
...
```